# InteractiveViewer scale for pinch and button zoom

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

How can I ensure the zoom works from center for both pinch zoom and button zoom. I aligned it on topleft as it is better for pinch zoom. However `Alignment.center` is better for button zoom. I am working on this tool [https://vidution.com/](https://vidution.com)

I think following two code lines are important in this case.

`alignment: Alignment.topLeft,`

`transformationController.value = (Matrix4.identity()..scale(scale));`

Here is a reference code.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double scale = 1.0;
  TransformationController transformationController = TransformationController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    transformationController.value = (Matrix4.identity()..scale(scale));

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Interactive Viewer Example'), centerTitle: true),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          InteractiveViewer(
            transformationController: transformationController,
            trackpadScrollCausesScale: true,
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.teal.shade100,
              width: 500,
              height: 500,
              child: const Center(child: Text('Alignment Example')),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      scale = scale + .25;
                    });
                    transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()..scale(scale);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.zoom_in)),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      scale = scale - .25;
                    });
                    transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()..scale(scale);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.zoom_out)),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the dartpad reference
https://dartpad.dev/?id=5eb289670122ff0cc090ce42b477bd1d